# A locally bounded family must not be a bounded family

Tags: functional-analysis

I have read that a locally bounded family is not a bounded family, and that the following family shows that:
$\mathcal{F} = \{ f_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, $f_n : \mathbb{E} \to \mathbb{C}$, $f_n(z) =n z^n$. Where $\mathbb{E}  = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \vert z \vert < 1\}$

(So that this is a locally bounded family but not a bounded family)

Unfortunately I am stuck at both claims.

The definitions are as follows:

**Def. bounded family:** A familiy $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{O} (D)$ is called bounded in a subset $A \subset D$, if there exists a real number $M > 0$ s.t. for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$ it holds that $\vert f \vert _A \leq M$.

**Def locally bounded family:** A family $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{O} (D)$ is called locally bounded in $D$ if for each point $z \in D$ there exists a neighborhood $U \subset D$ s.t. $\mathcal{F}$ is bounded in $U$.

What confuses me the most is that on one hand we have the times $n$ in $f_n(z) =n z^n$, on the other hand there is the to the power of $n$. So as $n$ gets bigger, $z^n$ gets smaller, as $z \in \mathbb{E}$.

What I have tried/where I am stuck:

Claim 1: $\mathcal{F}$ is not bounded.
Proof: To show this, we have to show, that there exists no $M>0$ s.t. for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$ it holds that $\vert f \vert _A \leq M$, or equivalently that $\sup\limits_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \sup \limits_{z \in \mathbb{E}} \vert f(z) \vert = \infty$. For a fixed $f \in \mathcal{F}$ we have:
$$ \sup \limits_{z \in \mathbb{E}} \vert f(z) \vert = \sup \limits_{z \in \mathbb{E}} n \vert z^n \vert = n \cdot 1^n = n $$

Then
$$ \sup\limits_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \sup \limits_{z \in \mathbb{E}} \vert f(z) \vert = \sup\limits_{f \in \mathcal{F}} n = \infty$$
I can say that the last equation holds because $\sup\limits_{f \in \mathcal{F}}$ is like $f_\infty$, so $n = \infty$.

Claim 2: $\mathcal{F}$ is locally bounded.
Proof: To show this, we have to show that for each point $z \in D$ there exists a neighborhood $U \subset D$ s.t. $\mathcal{F}$ is bounded in $U$. In this claim we use the following Lemma: A family $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{B})$ in a ball $B_r(c)$, $r>0$ is locally bounded in $B$ iff $\mathcal{F}$ is bounded in every ball $B_\rho (c)$, $\rho < r$.
With that we have to show that our family $\mathcal{F}$ is bounded in every ball $B_\rho (0)$, $\rho < 1$, i.e. $\sup\limits_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \sup \limits_{z \in B_\rho (0)} \vert f(z) \vert < \infty$.
For a fixed $f \in \mathcal{F}$ we have:
$$ \sup \limits_{z \in B_\rho (0)} \vert f(z) \vert = n \cdot \sup \limits_{z \in B_\rho (0)} \vert z^n \vert = n \cdot \rho ^n $$

Then
$$ \sup\limits_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \sup \limits_{z \in B_\rho (0)} \vert f(z) \vert = \sup\limits_{f \in \mathcal{F}} n \cdot \rho ^n$$

Now I have the problem that $n$ gets very big and $\rho ^n$ gets very small. How can I conclude from here on, that this is $< \infty$?

Proof of the Lemma:
$\Rightarrow$:  We assume that a family $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{O} (B)$ in a ball $B_r(c)$, $r>0$ is locally bounded in $B$. We want to show that it is then bounded in every ball $B_\rho(c)$, $\rho < r$.
Is there a trick for proving this?

$\Leftarrow$: We assume that $\mathcal{F}$ is bounded in every $B_\rho (c)$, $\rho <r$ and want to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is locally bounded in $B_r(c)$. Isn't this direction just clear by the definition of locally bounded? So by the definition of locally bounded, we have to show that for every $z \in B_r(c)$ there exists a nhood $U \subset B_r(c)$ s.t. $\mathcal{F}$ is bounded in $U$. We could take the balls $B_\rho(c)$, $\rho <r$ as $U$. But what about the points "between" the balls $B_\rho (c)$ (where here $\rho$ is the biggest possible) and $B_r (c)$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am sorry, I tried to write down as much as I got now. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I continued the proofs in my question with your help. I think Claim 1 is pretty clear now. For Claim 2 I am stuck with my problem that n is growing and the "to the power of n" is shrinking. 

I also added the Lemma, I'd love to see that proof. I wrote my attempt for both sides.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Oh alright, I added this and posted a self-answer. Thank you very much for your help!
About the Lemma: I am still very curious how the proof of this would work, do you maybe know how it goes or where I could find it?

Comment: For the lemma, *you proved $\Leftarrow$, which is all you needed!*

Comment: To prove $\Rightarrow$, use that for every $\rho<r$, the closed ball $K:=\overline{B_\rho(c)}$ is a [compact subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Compactness_of_subsets) of $B_r(c)$: given that every $z\in K$ has a neighborhood $U_z\subset B_r(c)$ on which $\mathcal F$ is bounded, $(U_z)_{z\in K}$ is an open cover of $K$, from which you can extract a *finite* subcover $(U_{z_1},\dots,U_{z_r})$. If $M_k$ is a bound for $\mathcal F$ on $U_{z_k}$, $\max(M_1,\dots,M_r)$ is then a bound on $U_{z_1}\cup\dots\cup U_{z_r}\supset K$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim 1: $\mathcal{F}$ is not bounded.
Proof: To show this, we have to show, that there exists no $M>0$ s.t. for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$ it holds that $\vert f \vert _A \leq M$, or equivalently that $\sup\limits_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \sup \limits_{z \in \mathbb{E}} \vert f(z) \vert = \infty$. For a fixed $f\in \mathcal{F}$ we have $f=f_n$ for some $n\in \Bbb N$, and:
$$ \sup \limits_{z \in \mathbb{E}} \vert f(z) \vert = \sup \limits_{z \in \mathbb{E}} n \vert z^n \vert = n \cdot 1^n = n $$

Then
$$ \sup\limits_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \sup \limits_{z \in \mathbb{E}} \vert f(z) \vert = \sup\limits_{n\in \Bbb N} n = \infty$$

Claim 2: $\mathcal{F}$ is locally bounded.
Proof: To show this, we have to show that for each point $z \in D$ there exists a neighborhood $U \subset D$ s.t. $\mathcal{F}$ is bounded in $U$. In this claim we use the following Lemma: A family $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{B})$ in a ball $B_r(c)$, $r>0$ is locally bounded in $B$ iff $\mathcal{F}$ is bounded in every ball $B_\rho (c)$, $\rho < r$.
With that we have to show that our family $\mathcal{F}$ is bounded in every ball $B_\rho (0)$, $\rho < 1$, i.e. $\sup\limits_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \sup \limits_{z \in B_\rho (0)} \vert f(z) \vert < \infty$.
For a fixed $f \in \mathcal{F}$ we have $f=f_n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, and:
$$ \sup \limits_{z \in B_\rho (0)} \vert f(z) \vert = n \cdot \sup \limits_{z \in B_\rho (0)} \vert z^n \vert = n \cdot \rho ^n $$

Then
$$ \sup\limits_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \sup \limits_{z \in B_\rho (0)} \vert f(z) \vert = \sup\limits_{n\in \Bbb N} n \cdot \rho ^n < \infty.$$

Where the "$< \infty$" holds, as [$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n \cdot \rho^n = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2981843) and every converging sequence is bounded.

Comment: great, thanks for the polishing. I see that it makes more sense like that.

Comment: Ok, then if you agree, please correct the end of your answer. (Incidentally, another argument could be an explicit upperbound. $\max_{x\in\Bbb R}x\cdot\rho^x$ is not extremely difficult to calculate. But the argument that every converging sequence is bounded seems simpler.)

Comment: i changed the $\to 0$ to $< \infty$ now.

Comment: I added a justification, I hope you are happy with that. Unfortunately, I don't know how to add the link to the other question where it's shown that the limes goes to 0.

Comment: Thank you, for your correction. I accepted my answer now.